# how do you convert linq query ToList

Tags: linq

How does one convert a query to a list?

I've tried several different ways to ToList this query, but I'm not able to be successful.

```
var parent =
from s in Students
where s.Id==5027
select new { 
    ID_PK = (s.CaseOwnerIdAspnet_Users.User_ID_FKDYN_User_Profile.Organization_ID_FKDYN_Organization.Parent_ID_FK == null ?
    (int) s.CaseOwnerIdAspnet_Users.User_ID_FKDYN_User_Profile.Organization_ID_FKDYN_Organization.ID_PK
    :
    (int) s.CaseOwnerIdAspnet_Users.User_ID_FKDYN_User_Profile.Organization_ID_FKDYN_Organization.Parent_ID_FK)
    };
```

Comment: `var parent = (from s in Students where s.Id == 5027 select new { ... }).ToList();`

Comment: Why were you not succesfull? You don't know how to do it or trying to use .ToList() you encountered some errors? Provide more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
var list =parent.ToList();
```